# How to use paramerized query in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and expressjs,Right now i am trying to execute select query , query is working successfully but i want two things

```
1) How to convert this query to "paramerized query" ?
2) Whenever i am trying to get "total rows" then i am getting "[object object] "
```

Here is my current code

```
static async addServiceDetail(shopId,serviceId,genderTypeId,price,serviceName)
    {
        const sql = `SELECT id from hc_servicesdetail WHERE shopId='${shopId}' AND  serviceId='${serviceId}' AND genderTypeId='${genderTypeId}'`;
        const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql);
         console.log('total rows are'+ rows); // getting [object object]
        if(rows<1)
            {
                  //further code  
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters as an array to the `execute` call, then log the rows to the console:

```
let shopId = 'B';
let serviceId = 'k';
let genderTypeId = 'F';
let sql = 'SELECT id from hc_servicesdetail WHERE shopId=? AND serviceId=? AND genderTypeId=?';
const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql, [shopId, serviceId, genderTypeId]);
console.log('Rows:', rows)
```

The output will look something like this:

```
Rows: [ { id: 1 } ]
```

Comment: its working fine,Than you so much for help

Answer (score 0):

For printing the value that is contained inside results just use results.

```
console.log(rows)
```

Comment: and how to convert/write "parameterized query" (select query) ?

Comment: Here is how to add parameters in SQL query.

    `const sql = \`SELECT id from hc_servicesdetail WHERE shopId='?' AND  serviceId='?' AND genderTypeId='?'\`;   const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql, [val1, val2, val2]);`

Single quotes are used to encapsulate string data types.

Comment: sorry but your query is not working

Comment: what package and database are you using